# Why do the equivalents of “moody” in other Germanic languages mean “courageous”?

Tags: english, cognates

If it wasn’t clear, “moody” is a word found in the English language. It generally implies a sense of melancholy on the thing it is describing.

However, in other Germanic languages, the cognates of this word mean “courageous”. For example, in Dutch, “moedig” means “brave”. Why does English have such a unique definition  for the same word?

Comment: The OED has the earliest-attested English meaning as 'brave', found in Beowulf. This meaning is obsolete. A second obsolete meaning is 'haughty, headstrong'. The surviving meaning of 'melancholic', 'given to mood swings', and so on is attested as early as the thirteenth century. I would just point out that all three of these meanings characterize Achilles in the Iliad, and so the semantic path is far from implausible.

Comment: But it doesn’t seem like other Germanic languages have these alternate meanings. Where does English get them from?

Comment: That I don't know, and I'd be surprised if anyone can give you a convincing answer beyond outlining a plausible path. There is much randomness in semantic drift.

Comment: (tangential thought experiment, please ignore if not interested:) if you have three languages with the same etymon in the same meaning at one point in history, and you look at them two thousand years later, would you think it more likely that the meaning has changed in none, one, two or all three of the languages? I would put the weight of probability on 0 and 1, probably leaning towards 0, all else being equal.

Comment: The complete and total answer to most "why?" question about language is "Because that's the way it is" You can trace the historical development of a change, but that still does not answer the question of why it happened there and then and didn't happen somewhere else or some other time.

Comment: @ColinFine as a language learner, the main interest in such similarities is for me to better remember words with similar etymologies in foreign languages. The “why” doesn’t necessarily matter in this case; the “how” is more important.

Comment: @ColinFine, that's a fix-point of the language of thought, so to speak, and the prototype is given by Descartes, cogito ergo sum. It specifically doesn't mean one should stop asking "why"

Answer (score 2):

There's a trivial association between *mood* and Ger. *Mut*, in which "bravery" is just a circumstantial entailment of the social expectations there and then entailed by the moral ethos of the time.

*Unmut* still rather corresponds to *mood*, in the bigger semantic field of "moral", "attitude", etc. Ger. *müde* conversely means "tired, sleepy", perhaps not from the same root (cf. *mew-, assume *dimm, fuzzy*), but certainly seen in connotations of *moody* (~ having *Unmut*).

Therefore, the adjective with *-y* must be secondary, half built from the noun, half from the root in *müde*, and thus not directly equivalent to *mutig*.

Further, *mood* might be comparable to *modus*, too (cp. *rile-midel* vis-a-vis ethics). Whereas *Mut* contrasts with *Wut* (anger, part. or adj. *wütend*; *Tollwut*, adj. *tollwütig*), *Hut* (alertness, chiefly in *auf der Hut sein*, cp. *hut, house*, v. *hüten, behüten* *(s)kew- "to cover, protect").

Further appearant compositions that have nothing much to do with bravery are *Anmut* (adj. *anmutig*, part. *anmutend*), *Schwermut* (adj. *schwermütig*), *Missmut* (adj. *missmutig*), *Mutwillen* (adv. *mutwillig*, part. *mutwillens*), *Gemüt* (literally the facility that embodies mood; cp. *Gemächt*, *Macht*, *might [and magic], …) and *gemütlich* (comfortable (e.g. of a couch), pleasant, light (of a stroll in the park). Also cp. *Vergnügen, genügen, genug, Genüge* versus *modesty, moderation*.

Further, *motzen*, *to mutter*, and several more entries in the Lexicon under *m-* might become conflated, initially, who knows. [TODO: what do Kronnen say?] As far as I know, Middle High German Umlautung (Schwebelaut) is not fully understood. [PS: I had first written <strike>*missmütig*</strike> under influence of *schwermütig*--that's how easy these can change. I noticed when proof-reading, but still had to confer the spellchecker, lol.]

Conversely, German *brav* rather exclusively describes an obedient, well mannered subject (of children, dogs, etc). It's probably a loan from Romance languages (viz. *bravo*), I assume, thus uninteresting. But it shows an analogic semantic development in English.

---

Further comparisons, e.g. with *Beruf* (calling, job-title, burden) read as *obedience* (call and response, responsibility), thus further *Dienst* (work, service) would be highly speculative in search of a parallel in *Mut*.

Also always confusing: *courage*, *care* and Lat. *cura* are not appearantly related [wiktionary].